# Send emails slowly with Java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, email, asynchronous, smtp

I have an application that sends emails to a group of users. My problem is there are a lots of users that I have to send one mail at once and the smpt server blocks. How can I send with spring mails to this users little by little?

Comment: `Thread.sleep()`; will pause your program.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a local MTA that supports queuing (such as Postfix) in satellite/relay mode. Have it relay to your real SMTP server. Make sure it is secure, i.e. can only relay from local requests.

Drop your emails in the local MTA. You can drop them as fast as you want, and your local MTA will send them to the remote SMTP server when it can.

Comment: The problems is i dont have installed postfix, i thinking something like push the sendMail method to a background process and ejecute 10,20 or 30 mails in intervaled times. This aproach is good?

Comment: you'd be creating your own email queue, duplicating an MTA's queue, so probably a waste of your time. Are you unable to install an MTA on that server?

Comment: I was not able to create a postfix server, and the cost is to much for the client. But i implemented a asynchronous task with spring and then use quartz for send slowly every mail.

Answer (score 0):

Break your app into two pieces. One piece prepares the email and gives the messages to a backend service. The backend service runs all the time, and when it has email to send, it pauses between messages to avoid overloading your mail server. There are numerous ways to link the two, but a really simple one is to simply write small batches of email requests into files in an incoming directory. Just write maybe 10 emails to a file, then write some END OF BATCH indicator, close it, open a new file and write some more. The backend task will then look for files in this incoming directory. When it finds a file it will attempt to read the whole thing, then look for the END OF BATCH indicator. If it is not there, then retry (or continue reading). Once you have a full batch, send one email to the mail server, pause for x second, send the next and so on. You will have to experiment with the value of x to find a reliable one that still gets the mail out, i.e. prevents the incoming directory from filling the disk. 
Of course, once you have sent a batch, delete the file containing it.

A much better way to do this is to integrate Camel (from Apache) into the two apps and define endpoints that use some kind of messaging to send email requests, for instance JMS or SEDA. But you would still separate the communication with the mail server into a separate task with a buffer between that and the main app. In effect, because the mail server cannot buffer enough work for you, you have to put a buffer on your side to keep things running smoothly.